# Xcode Simulator Symbol not found: _SimCarPlayPropertyKeyHasBackButton

Tags: ios, xcode

This error occurs when I run `open -a Simulator`, is there anyone could help me?

*Please omit the repeated words, I don't how many words is detailed enough. This error occurs when I run `open -a Simulator`, is there anyone could help me?
This error occurs when I run `open -a Simulator`, is there anyone could help me?*

The error information likes this:

```
Process:               Simulator [51218]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               11.0 (912.1)
Build Info:            Indigo-912001000000000~157
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [51218]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-17 22:21:50.331 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y901)
Anonymous UUID:        BDE6C29F-221A-CBF6-F8D6-78C567E56E88

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B1B2C3FF-69B2-4397-B3F4-4D8260B0F4E9

Time Awake Since Boot: 1900000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       37000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _SimCarPlayPropertyKeyHasBackButton
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
```

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the version of CoreSimulator on your system is older than what Simulator.app expects.

Launching Xcode.app for the first time after an upgrade should cause it to update CoreSimualtor.framework.

Please launch Xcode.app to intall the updated package, or run `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` from Terminal.

Comment: I executed `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` already, it does not work.

Comment: Then I suggest just manually installing the package, eg: `sudo installer -pkg /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/XcodeSystemResources.pkg -target /`